# How do you find the PCI memory hole on x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, osdev, pci

I ask as it's really hard to find solid/official documentation on a lot of things to do with x86 programming beyond the basic bootloader/real mode interrupts/protected mode/write to VGA memory tasks one would do when learning about basic OS development.

After reading the Wikipedia articles about x86 architecture, chipsets, I/O Controller Hub, and PCI/PCI Express to get a better understanding, it is apparent that there are 2 ways of accessing PCI interfaces: I/O ports and Memory Mapped IO.

I (incorrectly?) understand that using x86 I/O ports is considered a legacy method and is not recommended, so using the PCI MMIO access method (through the PCI "memory hole") would be preferable, but I cannot find any guides/information/source code that do not use I/O ports like 0xCF8/0xCFC to access/probe PCI, do configuration etc.

Where is the PCI memory hole? How can I access/probe PCI purely through MMIO?

I tried reading the Linux PCI code, but I am too unfamiliar with it and Linux kernel structure to have any proper idea about what is going on or how to properly navigate around, so anyone in the know who could clarify how it accomplishes this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: There are three PCI address spaces: configuration, I/O, and memory. It's the configuration address space that's mapped into that "hole" you're talking about on PCI-Express systems, though the Enhanced Configuration Access Mechanism. The configuration space is used (among other things) by the BIOS (for boot devices) or the OS (everything else) to configure where in the CPU's I/O or memory space each PCI device's I/O and/or memory regions (if any) are mapped to. The location of ECAM mapped configuration space can be found through ACPI.

Comment: Great informative response, thanks! (Apologies I cannot upvote as I am new here).

Comment: People are voting to close this as off-topic because it is seeking an off-site resource, and indeed they are correct given the original wording of the question. However, I think there's a reasonable question here that is not intrinsically off-topic, so I've edited the question so that you are not seeking an off-site resource, but rather a canonical answer containing the actual information. That makes this on topic again, and the close votes should age away without the question ever getting closed. Feel free to revert my edits if you disagree, but be warned it may be closed.

Comment: From the comments, It seems taken for granted that a "PCI memory hole" exists, yet I'm never been aware of such a thing. ISA had a hole, the memory below 1MiB has a hole, but PCI? What hole are we talking about?

Comment: @margaret I assume he means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_hole), the space reserved on 32-bit x86 architectures in upper memory for hardware devices. Basically, what the Physical Address Extension (PAE) worked around in the Pentium Pro, if you're familiar with that.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @CodyGray !